# Azure File Storage Fetch All Files Recursively in a Single Request

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

The REST API documentation for the Azure File Service indicates that it can take a prefix for ListDirectoriesAndfiles(), but this only seems to only return direct descendants. Is it possible to get all descendants in a single request like it is with Blob storage?

Comment: File service not blob

Comment: Apologies for my redundant comment. I did not read the question carefully the first time. I have deleted my comment already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get all descendants in a single request like it is
>   with Blob storage?

No. The operation will list only 1 level of descendants. Essentially `ListDirectoriesAndfiles()` is a wrapper over [`List Directories and Files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-directories-and-files) REST API operation. From the REST API documentation:

> The List Directories and Files operation returns a list of files or
>   directories under the specified share or directory. **It lists the
>   contents only for a single level of the directory hierarchy.**